# List all flags of a file?

Tags: permissions, osx, ls

Is there a way to see a file's flags, such as hidden, schg, etc? I've got an rwxrwxrwx file that I can't edit, and I think a flag might be responsible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are talking about FreeBSD - from [man ls](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ls):

> ```
>  -o      Include the file flags in a long (-l) output.
> ```

So `ls -lo` should list all the file flags on FreeBSD.

Comment: Using Mac OSX, but works the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

On OS X 10.8, this is `ls -lO` now (with a capital O). The output from `man ls`:

```
-O      Include the file flags in a long (-l) output.
-o      List in long format, but omit the group id.
```

Comment: This is also valid on Mavericks, Yosemite & El Capitan.